# Artifactory configuration

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins file where one of the stage is to run the maven build. When Jenkins is running the below configuration it is stuck and it is not moving forward. This was working when I have used version 2.107.3, I have upgraded our Jenkins to 2.150.1 and I am facing this issue.

```
stage ('Artifactory configuration') {
 steps {
   script {
        def SERVER_ID = "Artifactory" 
        def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID
        def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'netstar', server: server
        buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
        rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true', buildInfo: buildInfo
       }
    }
}
```

`

[jenkins console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SDBU.png)

Comment: Hi, from the versions you provided it rather seems that you downgraded.

Comment: Apologies, it was 2.150.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open bug for this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55975

Current workaround is to downgrade to following versions

```
git plugin = 3.9.3 
git-client plugin = 2.7.6 
Artifactory plugin = 2.16.2
```